# How to use CursorLoader in non-activity and non-fragment class?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

This may be dumb question as am new for this cursor loader am bit confused whether my question is possible to achieve it or not, am trying to make common cursor loader for whole project, so far i have initialized separate  cursor loader in every activity where it is needed but now, am trying to make it in common class but the problem is am confused how to initialize the cursorloader in non activity class please can someone help me how to achieve this let me post what i have tried so far

This is the class where i implemented cursorloader:

```
 public class CursorLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  private Context mcontext;
  private Cursor  mcursor;
  public CursorValue cursorValue;

    public void initCursor(Cursor cursor,Context context) {
        this.mcontext=context;
        this.mcursor=cursor;
        if(this.mcontext instanceof Activity){
            ((Activity)this.mcontext).getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null,this); //here you can init loader
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("context should implement activity class");
        }
       }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new android.content.CursorLoader(mcontext, IncidentDAO.DB_SF_Incident, null, null, null, null){

            ForceLoadContentObserver mObserver=new ForceLoadContentObserver();
            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {

           if (mcursor != null) {
                    mcursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
                    mcursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), getUri());

                }
                return mcursor;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            cursorValue.getValue(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

in my activity class am trying to initialize like this:

```
 public class Incident extends AppCompatActivity implements CursorValue {
        private IncidentDAO incidentDAO;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.incident_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.incident_recyclerview);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Incident.this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

           CursorLoader cursorLoader=new CursorLoader();
            cursorLoader.cursorValue=Incident.this;
            Cursor c = incidentDAO.IncidentList();
            cursorLoader.initCursor(c,this);
        }
         @Override
        public void getValue(Cursor cursor) {
            final IncidentCursorAdapter incidentCursorAdapter = new IncidentCursorAdapter(Incident.this, cursor);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(incidentCursorAdapter);
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptytext);
            if (incidentCursorAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 && incidentCursorAdapter != null) {
                textView.setText("No Data Available");
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            incidentCursorAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(Cursor cursor) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Incident.this, IncidentView.class);
                    int is_localvendor = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IncidentModel.Incident_LocalVendor));
                    int is_generalclaim = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IncidentModel.Incident_IsGeneralClaim));
                    int is_partrequired = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IncidentModel.Incident_IsPartRequired));
                    int is_installationcall = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IncidentModel.Incident_IsInstallationCall));
                    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(IncidentModel.Incident_RegistrationID));
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("id", id);
                    bundle.putInt("generalclaim", is_generalclaim);
                    bundle.putInt("localvendor", is_localvendor);
                    bundle.putInt("partrequired", is_partrequired);
                    bundle.putInt("installationcall", is_installationcall);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
```

Am bit confused whether am doing it in wrong way or can someone tell me how to initialize cursor Thanks in advance!!

crash report:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver@42207168 is already registered.
                                                                                    at android.database.Observable.registerObserver(Observable.java:49)
                                                                                    at android.database.ContentObservable.registerObserver(ContentObservable.java:32)
                                                                                    at android.database.AbstractCursor.registerContentObserver(AbstractCursor.java:319)
                                                                                    at precisioninfomatics.servicefirst.HelperClass.CursorLoader$1.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:41)
                                                                                    at precisioninfomatics.servicefirst.HelperClass.CursorLoader$1.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:34)
                                                                                    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                                                                                    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                                                                                    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

This part causing crash:

```
 return new android.content.CursorLoader(mcontext, IncidentDAO.DB_SF_Incident, null, null, null, null){

            ForceLoadContentObserver mObserver=new ForceLoadContentObserver();
            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {

                if (mcursor != null) {
                    mcursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
                    mcursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), getUri());

                }
                return mcursor;
            }
        };
```

mcursor.registercontentobserver causing crash how to deal with!

Comment: Do you have some error?

Comment: no error nothing is display we need to initialize cursor loader but i can't initialize it how to do this!

Comment: Have you tried to cast context to activity class?

Comment: no how to do this can share some snippet on this

Comment: infact getloader manager cannot be ressolved in normal java class

Comment: `public void initCursor(Cursor cursor,Context context)` -> `public void initCursor(Cursor cursor,Activity activity)`

Comment: @pskink getting illegal argument expression see my edits

Comment: what is it: `LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new cursorLoader=new precisioninfomatics.servicefirst.HelperClass.CursorLoader();`? is it your java code?, first post your exact code, otherwise its hard to tell whats wrong

Comment: @pskink can you get it!

Comment: so where is `initLoader`? why dont you follow the example code in `LoaderManager` documentation?

Comment: check my edit @pskink

Comment: no, just see `LoaderManager` documentation and follow the sample code, what is `this.mcursor=cursor;` for? the cursor is returned from the loader, you dont have to pass any

Comment: @pskink let me tell on this is it possible to write common cursorloader like this or we need separate cursorloader for each activity

Comment: what is `Cursor` parameter in `initCursor` method for?

Comment: il pass the cursor from database to that parameter please check the code

Comment: did you try the code from `LoaderManager` documentation ? first try that sample and try to modify it do meet your needs

Comment: first let me tell you @pskink its working when i try with separate cursor loader for each activity but now am trying to make it common.  It's working when i try with seaparate cursor loader for each activity.

Comment: what is Cursor parameter in initCursor method for?  if you have a `Cursor` with data what do you need any loader for?

Comment: to refresh the content when database value get changed i have cursorloader. return cursor loader method in loadinbackground methods need cursor as return value so i have passed cursor value.

Comment: ok so you are passing any `Cursor` just because you have to return some `Cursor` from `loadInBackground`? and where do you load your data?

Comment: from sqlite database and in override method in activity i pass that cursor value to adapter.

Comment: no, you are loading your data here: `Cursor c = incidentDAO.IncidentList();` inside `Activity#onCreate`, then you dont need any loader - your data is already loaded

Comment: correct automatic referesh is not possible if i pass that cursor to adapter so need cursorloader to watch whenever my content gets changed

Comment: again: if you are loading your data in the ui thread (Activity#onCreate), what do you need any loader for? do you know how loader framework works?

Comment: loader framework will look for data whenever contents get changed .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void initCursor(Cursor cursor,Context context) {
          this.mcontext=context;
         this.mcursor=cursor;

if(this.context instanceof Activity) {
((Activity)this.context).getLoaderManager() //here you can init loader 
      } else { 
             throw new ClassCastException("context should implement activity class");
      }
//....
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: first its working getting list but onclick in my interface getting Observer android.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver@420006f8 is already registered. this error what should be the problem.

Comment: Hmmm. Can you post whole crashlog? What string of code produce this error?

Comment: i have posted please check it

Comment: try to move 
`ForceLoadContentObserver mObserver=new ForceLoadContentObserver();`
this into `loadInBackground` method

Comment: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() when i put forceloadobserver inside loadinbackinground

Comment: how to get rid of this